# Isolate x in this equation

Tags: exponential-function

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could please isolate "x" by manipulating the following equation:
$$(2^xR)+x=(x-1)p$$

Comment: $2^x R + x = (x-1)p$ in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this can't be done with ordinary functions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), so it can't be solved by pure algebra techniques; there's no closed form solution.

Comment: Damn.  I've been trying to derive a simple metric for solving a computing problem.  This formula is the only one I've been able to create which will indicate a valid value for p.  "R" is actually a constant.  If "x" is an integer for a given prime number "p" then it would indicate the prime number I'm looking for.

Comment: If $R$ is required to be an integer, my guess is that there would be very few prime numbers that satisfy your equation. I would suggest modular arithmetic in this case.

Answer (score 4):

There is an explicit solution for $x$ using Lambert $W$ function. The solution is given by
$$x=\frac{p}{p-1}-\frac{W\left(-\frac{2^{\frac{p}{p-1}} R \log (2)}{p-1}\right)}{\log
   (2)}$$ In the case where the argument of the Lambert $W$ function is small or large, there are very nice approximations which at least would give you a reasonable estimate of the solution for starting a Newton procedure.

In fact, any equation which can be rewritten as  $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has an explicit solution which involves Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Wikipedia says Lambert functions use a complex number, denoted by "W", which makes this solution useless for my application.  I'm looking for a rational number value of "x", which I can then test to see if it's an integer.  Both p and R are known quantities.  Even if it weren't complex, "W" would at the very least be an additional variable (thus I would be unable to solve for "x").

Comment: @JasonA. I am sorry ! I did not notice any restriction in the post. Cheers :-)

Comment: You may be confused, $W$ is a function known as the Lambert $W$ function. It is not a variable. It can take complex or real valued arguments

Comment: @TylerHG. Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer to clarify each occurence of $Lambert$. Cheers :-)